# Interpreting procrustes output in vegan

Tags: vegan

I'm trying to figure out how I should be interpreting the output of a procrustes analysis in vegan. Specifically, what is the difference between the sum of squares results in the `summary(procrustes_object)` vs `protest` functions?

Here is a toy example:

```
library(vegan)

#some environmental data
env <- read.table(header=TRUE, row.names="site",text="site  temp    rainfall    ph
A   11  600 6
B   13  550 8
C   13  500 6
D   13  450 8
E   14  400 7
F   15  400 7")

#some animal abundances
animals <- read.table(header=TRUE,  row.names="site",text="site frogs   birds   mammals insects spiders
A   54  45  32  88  77
                      B 64  54  30  85  74
                      C 50  49  28  81  50
                      D 30  43  26  84  60
                      E 13  44  24  86  40
                      F 14  51  22  50  22")

#some tree abundances
trees <- read.table(header=TRUE,  row.names="site",text="site   elm oak maple   yew willow  pine
A   1   55  44  81  34  88
B   3   58  50  78  40  87
C   7   56  40  74  33  75
D   3   54  24  77  22  80
E   1   55  10  79  14  70
F   7   57  11  43  15  61")

#run CCAs for animals and trees against available environmental data
cca_animals <- cca(animals, env)
cca_trees <- cca(trees, env)

pro1 <- procrustes(cca_animals, cca_trees) #run procrustes to compare animal and tree CCAs
summary(pro1) #procrustes sum of squares = 0.786
protest(cca_animals, cca_trees) #procrustes sum of quares = 0.047
#correlation in a symmetric procrustes rotation=0.976
```

The two sum of squares results I get are very different, but I'm not sure which I should be using. Also, how is this related to the "correlation" value in the protest output? As ever, I'm sure that this question is largely motivated by my ignorance of basic statistics, but as always, remedial schooling is very appreciated.

Comment: I should add, what I'm trying to see in this example is whether animal and tree communities have a similar structure against the tested environmental variables

Comment: According to documentation, `protest` runs symmetric Procrustes analysis, whereas `procrustes` defaults to non-symmetric analysis.

Answer (score 5):

The main difference between basic Procrustes and PROTEST is that `protest` is always symmetric whereas `procrustes` defaults to non-symmetric: `procrustes` rotates one solution to another (target). Your question is clearly symmetric, and you should use `procrustes` with argument `symmetric = TRUE` or  equivalently `protest`.

I am not sure that Procrustes analysis is very useful in your case. You have two constrained ordination, and the constraints are equal in both. The constrained ordinations will also be equal if you look at all constrained axes and LC scores (which are linear combinations of constraints). You see this if you try

```
plot(procrustes(cca_trees, cca_animals, scores="lc", symmetric=TRUE, choices=1:3))
```

If you have a plenty of constraints and only look at the first dimensions, then you can have some differences (in this case very little). Also, when you look at the Weighted Averages scores (which are the default in `procrustes`), you get some more scatter. However, you should think yourself if the analysis can be usefully interpreted. That is a non-technical question not for the StackOverflow.

Comment: Why are the residuals of procrustes(cca_trees, cca_animals) different from the residuals of procrustes(cca_animals, cca_trees)? Here is my [related question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/272848/residuals-of-symmetric-procrustes-analyses-are-not-symmetric).

Comment: The default Procrustes analysis is non-symmetric: one matrix (target) is kept unchanged, and the other one is rotated to that. If you want to get symmetric Procrustes analysis, you got to set argument `symmetric = TRUE`.

Comment: I read carefully before commenting and I already had set this argument to `TRUE` and the statistic is the same between `protest(A,B)` and `protest(B,A)`. But the residuals are different. You can see it for yourself by clicking on the link I posted in the comment above your comment.

Comment: Yes indeed. This seems to be the case. It really is a different process to rotate A to B and measure residuals in **unrotated** B than rotate B to A and measure residuals  in **unrotated** A. The goodness-of-fit statistics can be made symmetric, and the rotation angles are at least mirror-symmetric.

Comment: Would co-inertia analysis offer the possibility to have symmetric "residuals" (distances to realisations in co-inertia space)?

I know this is not a proper Stack Overflow discussion. That is why I posted in CrossValidated. But we can keep discussing this here.